# -bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I had a lot of problems with python and I think I screwed things up. When I type in to terminal

```
$which python
```

it returns

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Then when I type

```
$pip install google
```

It says

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed pip using Python 3, you may have to run `pip3` instead of `pip`. Additionally, you should probably use something like `virtualenv` or [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html) to manage different environments and packages.

You can also try re-installing `pip` using the `get-pip.py` script from [pip's installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html).

> Install pip
>
> To install pip, securely download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
>
> Then run the following (which may require administrator access):
>
> ```
> python get-pip.py
> ```
>
> If `setuptools` is not already installed, `get-pip.py` will install setuptools for you.

If you still have problems, try installing virtualenv and the packages from scratch and see if it works:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ venv/bin/pip install google-cloud-storage
(venv) $ venv/bin/python -c 'import google.cloud.storage'
```

Comment: I love you so much! You are the greatest thing ever!

Comment: Still I'm getting the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google

Comment: Even after "Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 google-2.0.1" in terminal

Comment: @GoopieGoogpie I suggest you try installing virtualenv or Anaconda and try re-creating your environment from scratch. It's likely you'll have better luck with that approach. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Once I've created the virtual environment how do I make my files use it? (I'm using ATOM to run python files with the script plugin)

Comment: @GoopieGoogpie You have to 'activate' the new environment using the commands in the code block in my answer. `virtualenv venv` creates a new environment called `venv` and `source venv/bin/activate` will set the directory that pip downloads packages too. Follow the code example and it should work. If this helped, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do `ln -s /usr/bin/pip` and `ln -s /usr/bin/pip3` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/`.

That fixed it for me.  After that, I had to force pip to upgrade itself again.